# how we can login without password in dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

I have a SSO scenario where users will be in the database but they won't have a password, in that case, how we can log in without a password.

We have below line which logs in user by creating cookies:

```
var objUser = UserController.ValidateUser(PortalId, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, "", PortalSettings.PortalName, ipAddress, loginStatus)
```

Is there any other way to log in without a password? I have a custom SSO which won't have password in database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [UserController.UserLogin](https://docs.dnncommunity.org/api/DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.html#DotNetNuke_Entities_Users_UserController_UserLogin_System_Int32_DotNetNuke_Entities_Users_UserInfo_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) method to accomplish this.

You simply pass it the PortalId, the UserInfo for the user, and a few other parameters and you are set.